# Why are takeR, dropR and splitAtR missing from Data.Sequence?

Tags: haskell, containers, sequence

`Data.Sequence` has `takeWhileR` and `dropWhileR` for efficient deconstruction of `Seq`s from the right. However, `takeR`, `dropR` and `splitAtR` are conspicuously absent. `take` and `drop` are implemented in terms of `splitAt`. So, do finger trees not admit an efficient `splitAtR` or was this functionality not included for some other reason?

(Separate but somewhat related question: Would a naive `dropR` implementation in terms of `viewR` perform decently well?)

This question is based on [`containers-0.5.6.3`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Sequence.html).

Comment: @dfeuer would be the expert on Data.Sequence, although I don’t know if I can notify him this way.

Comment: Github issue: [https://github.com/haskell/containers/issues/159](https://github.com/haskell/containers/issues/159).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`length`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Sequence.html#v:length) is O(1), so `splitAt` suffices to define everything you need, in an efficient way.

```
 splitAtR i s = splitAt (length s - i) s
 takeR i s = snd $ splitAtR i s
 dropR i s = fst $ splitAtR i s
```

According to the docs, `splitAt` costs `O(log(min(i,length s-i)))`, so by symmetry `splitAtR` costs the same (just an additional `+O(1)`, which we can neglect).

Comment: That is a very good point, thank you very much. I shall ask @dfeuer why these definitions are not in the library.